# Problems in updating AWS .NET SDK in a UWP project from v3.1.10 to v3.3.0.1

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-s3, uwp, aws-sdk, windows-10-universal

I am building a UWP application in *Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25.425.01 Update 3* with *Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055*. The current version of *AWS .NET SDK* I am using is **v3.1.0**. And everything works fine so far.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC9rM.png)

I want to update the SDK to **Latest Stable 3.3.0.1** for some newer AWS S3 APIs support that I need for my application. But when I try installing it, the following error throws up.

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEbl1.png)

However, when I go to the *Update* option, select the SDK package and hit update, it successfully gets updated.

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLq7K.png)

[Image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/184tx.png)

[Image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32PSS.png)

But then when I rebuild my solution, I get the following errors.

[Image6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBaNv.png)

I am unable to figure out the real issue behind this problem. Kindly help me resolve it.

*Note : The project name and some file names are hidden due to confidentiality agreements.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that [AWSSDK.Core V3.3.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Core/3.3.0.1) added some .Net dependencies which is not compatible in UWP.

For example: [System.Threading.Thread](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Thread/)

You will get the same result if you try to install this package directly in UWP project

While [AWSSDK.Core 3.1.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Core/3.1.10) just have three dependencies:

```
Microsoft.Net.Http (>= 2.2.29) 
PCLStorage (>= 1.0.2) 
PCLCrypto
```

That's the reason you see these exception in VS:

```
Install-Package : System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm.
```

So you have to keep working on the 3.1 version and report this issue to AWS side

**------Update 09/29/2016------**

> Is there any workaround to get V3.3.0.1 in my project

There is a workaround

1. Create a **Windows Runtime Component** for Universal **Windows 8.1**:
   [image]
2. Add AWSSDK.S3 package for this **WRC**
3. Add this WRC as reference in your UWP project:

[image]

Comment: Is there any workaround to get V3.3.0.1 in my project, because there are many functions from various namespaces that are missing from the older version??

Comment: @sanster23 Yes, please see my updated answer **Update 09/29/2016**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response  _  I also wanted to ask you that The documentation of AWSSDK V3.3.0.1 shows the Encryption and TransferUtility(upload and download directory etc.) but when I installed the sdk in Visual Studio these are missing. 
So is that a bug too..
or a problem on my end??

Comment: @sanster23 Looks like Encrypion API has not ready to use, but Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility is working.

Comment: TransferUtility works but the upload and download **Directory** methods are not available